# Obter lista de objetos Persistidos JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Olá, como faço para obter a lista de objetos persistidos ante de comita-lo no BD. Segue o exemplo a baixo:

```
Pessoa p = new Pessoa("Joao", 21);
Pessoa p2 = new Pessoa("Pedro", 17);
Pessoa p3 = new Pessoa("Maria", 32);

//Entendo que nesse momento os dados ainda não estão salvos no banco
//Preciso obter essa lista para alterar as propriedades de alguns objetos
manager.persist(p);
manager.persist(p2);
manager.persist(p3);


//Comitando para salvar no banco
manager.getTransation().begin();
manager.getTransation().commit();
```

Comment: Seus objetos estão no escopo do método, porque você precisa da lista deles? Se você precisa do id gerado na persistencia, o método `persiste` retorna o id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você quer o ID, você precisa abrir a transação antes do persist. Você consegue obter o ID do persist desta maneira, usando o flush():

```
manager.getTransation().begin();

manager.persist(p);
manager.persist(p2);
manager.persist(p3);

//depois do flush, p, p2 e p3 terão os IDs
manager.flush();

//Comitando para salvar no banco
manager.getTransation().commit();
```

Ou, você pode obter os IDs deles após o commit:

```
manager.getTransation().begin();

manager.persist(p);
manager.persist(p2);
manager.persist(p3);

//Comitando para salvar no banco
manager.getTransation().commit();

//depois disto, p, p2 e p3 terão os IDs
```

Recomendo evitar o uso do flush sempre que possível. Se sua intenção é apenas obter os IDs, faça isto após o commit().